# Salsa trombone harmonizer setup

Tags: effects-pedal, microphones, equipment

I am looking to set up a trombone harmonizer to play salsa, but I'm new to both salsa and electronic music. It seems like what I want is unusual and not so simple, but it might be possible to do 85% of it, and I want your advice on what software and hardware I need to assemble.

In salsa, it's typical for trombone sections to alternate between unison/octaves and dense, delicious chords. One nice example is Ruben Blades & Willie Colon's "Ligia Elena"; I especially want to mimic the effect [at 3:17](https://youtu.be/tglzDCUckHA?t=196) where the trombone section changes suddenly from unison to chords for extra punch. Other examples are [this](https://youtu.be/roDyPFiPJD0) adaptation of "Verde Luz" (see 2:00) and [this recording](https://youtu.be/b3_onR65taQ?t=212) of "Buscando Guayaba" (see 3:32 or 5:30).

This question is not about how to arrange trombone parts for a salsa band, but it's useful to dissect a little bit of what's out there, just to guess how smart my harmonizer rig needs to be. For "Buscando", some absolute hero has published a [youtube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apcmkE4PoRU) with the trombone section chords written out. At the start, the harmony seems simple enough: it's all white keys except two passing tones, which are raised or lowered a half step from the previous chord in all three trombones, and one can predict the lower parts from just the note in the top part. Soon after, there is a chord labeled Db7#11, which is way outside of the key (C) but could be taken from a canned or live piano given the right technology. There are also chords that follow neither the key nor the piano, such as 0:30 or 3:44, but I don't know if they're typical of salsa or more a feature of this specific group & album. There's also [perfectly good salsa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wHcpn7GFvE) with only one trombone, so I don't need to do everything; I think it would be nice just to have options for solo, octave doubling, and triads or 7th chords.

Now, the question: what equipment and software do I get? I'll need to capture the sound, specify a "scheme" with 1-2 pedals (solo, octave, or chords), and for the chords, I need to specify and shift the pitches. To capture the sound, I am thinking of using a Yamaha silent brass mute, and I just need to make sure it's the right kind of signal+plug for whatever's downstream. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHfs6fUMBwE) suggested it.

Where I'm really stuck is trying to learn about harmonizers. Do I need a physical device, or just software? How do I narrow it down to a manageable number of options? I saw a [fantastic demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbF9DPsU6Qs) of the TC Helicon Harmony G-XT. It seems you can set it to either listen to a guitar, or use a fixed key, and you can switch modes with your toes on the "A/B switch". That is typical according to SE.

[(Vocal) Harmonizer Pedals: How do live performers use them?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/88109/vocal-harmonizer-pedals-how-do-live-performers-use-them?newreg=9cf00eb035a74a3584682a1e794e9c17)

So do I just get one of those Harmony GX-T's? If I do, would it be compatible with the minijack on the Yamaha pickup mute? Should I hold out for software that might be cheaper or easier or more harmonically flexible than the Harmony GX-T? Thank you!

Comment: From what little I know - they can be set for a key, and will harmonise within that key - diatonically. Or - they will listen to what chord is being played on guitar, and harmonise appropriately with that chord. Neither would appear to suit exactly what you need - and of course you'd need a mic to feed the machine anyway.